# Change buttoncolor

Tags: python, button, colors, tkinter

This is my script and I can't change the button's color. I don't know why...

Could you help me please?

```
bttn1 = Button(app)
bttn1.grid(row=1, column=1)
bttn1.configure(text = "Opdracht1")
```

Comment: The code shows no attempt to change the color. Why do you think this code should change the color?

Answer (score 0):

The foreground and background colors can be changed by the `fg` and `bg` options respectively:

```
from tkinter import Button, Tk

app = Tk()

bttn1 = Button(app, fg="red", bg="green")
bttn1.grid(row=1, column=1)
bttn1.configure(text="Opdracht1")

app.mainloop()
```

For more information, you can look at the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method) for `tkinter.Button`.